# Check when a user changes windows glass brush (Theme Color)

Tags: c#, winapi, aero, dwm

I have an application that uses the `windows glass brush` to set its controls' background to the same color at start up using `SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush` in `WPF`.

The problem is when the user change colors while the application still running, it won't update the background color. So i have to check when the user changes the theme color and then update the controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system sends a [`WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/wm-dwmcolorizationcolorchanged) to all top-level windows in response to a change in colorization color. Set up an event handler for this message to perform the re-initialization of your rendering resources.